# Destroy specific child object of prefab object in c# / Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, parent-child, collision-detection, destroy

I search a lot but couldn't find any answer. My problem: I instantiate several Gameobjects of a Prefab, each consists of two child objects: an obstacle and a scorezone. I want to destroy the scorezone (only of that specific instance), when the player touches the obstacle. So in Runtime my hierarchy looks like this:

- -ObjectPrefab(clone)
- ---Scorezone
- ---Obstacle
- -ObjectPrefab(Clone)
- ---Scorezone
- ---Obstacle
- ...

So I need to find ONE child gameobject (not the Transform) to then destroy it. I tried several codes but none worked. Here is the code with the three alternatives I tried, but none of them worked.:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {

if (collision.gameObject.tag == "obstacle") {
```

Alternative 1:

```
Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag("scorezone"));
```

Alternative 1 comes really close, but it destroys all scorezones of all instantiated objects.

Alternative 2:

```
Destroy(collision.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject.FindWithTag("scorezone"));
```

Alternative 2 would sound logic to me but I get the error message "Transform does not contain a definition for "FindWithTag".

Alternative 3:

```
foreach (Transform child in collision.gameObject.transform)
  {
   if (child.tag == "scorezone")
      {
        Destroy(child.gameObject);
      }
  }

}
```

Alternative 3 does not give an error but actually does nothing at all when the player hits the obstacle.

I really appreciate some help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Or iterate through the children on the colliders gameobject

Answer (score 0):

#### Store the reference!

If it is really a "prefab" so meaning you have it as an asset and instantiate it on runtime the best way (in my eyes and performance wise) would actually be to use a serialized field:

```c#
// Put this component on your obstacle
public class ObjectController : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Drag the according object here via the Inspector in the prefab
    // => when the prefab is Instantiated this field is already referenced
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _scoreZone;

    // Read-only access to the reference
    public GameObject ScoreZone => _scoreZone;
}
```

This field reference is stored together with your prefab asset. So every instance of the prefab already has its own child references set up.

and then do

```c#
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) 
{
    // Rather use CompareTag which is slightly more efficient
    // and adds some security (== silently fails if typo, CompareTag throws an exception instead)
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("obstacle")) 
    {  
        var controller = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<ObjectController>();
        if(controller) 
        { 
            Destroy(controller.ScoreZone); 
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### By Index

Alternatively but **error prone** you could simply use the index. You already know that there are only 2 childs, the first one being the Scorezone with index `0` so you can also do

```c#
if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("obstacle")) 
{  
    var scoreZone = collision.transform.parent.GetChild(0);
    Destroy(scoreZone); 
}
```

---

#### By Name

Using the name you could also use [`Find`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Find.html) - I would **not** recommend this! It is **error prone and slow**

```c#
if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("obstacle")) 
{  
    var scoreZone = collision.transform.parent.Find("ScoreZone");
    Destroy(scoreZone); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I tried your first solution. It didn't work, because the variable "controller" from your code is null, so it doesn't come to the if-statement. 
Is your "ObstacleController" the script which is attached to the prefab?

Maybe I should add: the collision function is attached to the player, which touches the instantiated prefab. Could that be the problem?

Comment: the `ObstacleController` as said in the comments should be attached to the `Obstacle` object you are colliding with (the one that also has the `Collider` attached)

Comment: Alternatively you could also attach it to the prefab itself and then use `GetComponentInParent`

Comment: It worked, thank you!!! You used "ObjectController" and then "ObstacleController" which is why I was confused, but now I got it :)

Comment: Ohh I see sorry for that confusion - fixed this now